# ASP.NET Suppress first try of ProcessPostData

Tags: asp.net, .net, lifecycle

We have some Web Controls in our framework which have a property `IsMustField`. If this property is set, the `CreateChildControls()` method changes some CSS and adds a JS Validator to the control. So far so good.

Now I'm trying to implement a slightly generic control. Some of its text fields are "must" fields when used in one case, but not in the others. The decision whether a field is a "must" field is done in the `OnLoad` method of the Control.

When I first open the page, everything is OK. As soon as I hit save and the postback is done, the page gets loaded. The initial value for the `IsMustField` Field is set with the value in the ascx (in this case `true`). Then it calls the `ProcessPostData()` for the first time. This calls the `EnsureChildControls()` method and therefore the `CreateChildControls()` method of our controls.
Since the CSS and the JS Validator are attached in this method, those will be added, as if the control is a must field. Afterwards, the `OnLoad()` Method of my generic control gets called and the `IsMustField` is set to `false`.

But since it already called the `CreateChildControls()` method, this has not the desired effect anymore.

Now my question would be: Is it possible to somehow suppress the `ProcessPostData` first try and only call it the second time, so it would load the controls, after my generic control has set the `IsMustField` to `false`? Or do I have to search for another solution.

I know the implementation is quite crappy, but I cannot change the framework, so I have no other choice.

Comment: What event is ProcessPostData called?

Comment: I think ProcessPostData is an event itself but not sure on that. First try is called directly before Page_Load, second try directly after Page_Load

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have two options: either set the IsMustField value earlier in the lifecycle, or do your "add-validator" behavior later in the lifecycle.  Here's a couple examples:

If you set the "isMustField" earlier in the page lifecycle (Page_Init() for example), it will get executed before ProcessPostData.  This approach assumes your isMustField-decision behavior is NOT dependent on user input (since it would happen before the ViewState is loaded).

The second option is to wait until later in the lifecycle to decide whether to apply the JS validator.  If you move that functionality to Page_PreRender (instead of CreateChildControls), then the page will get a chance to fully process the viewstate as well as any events, before you make the decision as to which controls are IsMustField = true.

See [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx) for info about Page Lifecycle.  IMO, it is the single best thing you can do, to be a strong ASP.NET developer!  :)

Comment: I had your option one in mind, problem there ist, that the controls that I need are not yet initialized at that moment. I assume the problem there is, that they are located in a FormView element. Anyway, if I want to search for the control, I receive null.
The problem with option two is, that I don't want to change the current way it's done, because this could have some serious impacts on the rest of the page...